What are some idioms where subtle differences in phrasing lead to a big difference in meaning?
I've seen a meme going around recently:

In 1000 years people won't understand the difference between "butt dial" and "booty call" and THAT is why the Bible can't be a reliable resource.

Of course, classicists devote a lot of time and effort to properly understanding the language and cultural context of ancient texts, in order to avoid this problem. But it got me wondering: do we know of any Latin or Greek idioms like this, where a small difference in wording leads to a huge difference in meaning?
(In English, "butt" and "booty" are synonyms, as are "dial" and "call", but a "butt dial" is when you call someone accidentally with your phone in your pocket (you're dialling with your butt) and a "booty call" is when you call someone to proposition them (you're calling for, well…booty).)

The examples given are better described as "noun compounds". once read an interesting article about it (I think it was this ). The point is that those noun compounds are inherently terse and require the community context to fill the gap. That context is not necessarily related to time/age at all (otherwise no explanation would have been required here in the addendum. In other words: in 1000 miles (not years) people don't get it )

from that article: " A house boat, for example, is a boat that functions like a house, but a housecoat is a coat you wear in a house, and a housewife fits neither pattern. There is no general algorithm that yields a predictable meaning for a compound. A reasonable guess is often possible but sometimes, you just have to know."

It's the classic joke: the literary teacher explaining connotation and denotation through the difference between "forgive me father, for I have sinned" and "sorry daddy, I've been naughty."
